# Categorize using spark sql

Tags: sql, database, apache-spark

I have a table like following [image]

I want to summeraize it in to following table

[image]

How to do it using at least sql?

**Edit**
class3 count should be 2. That's a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done in SQL as below

```
SELECT Org, SUM(CASE WHEN class='class1' THEN 1 ELSE O END) As Class1Count,
       SUM(CASE WHEN class='class2' THEN 1 ELSE O END) As Class2Count,
       SUM(CASE WHEN class='class3' THEN 1 ELSE O END) As Class3Count,
       SUM(CASE WHEN class='class4' THEN 1 ELSE O END) As Class4Count
FROM tableName
GROUP By Org
```